# How does James–Stein Estimator Works for Categorical Encoding

Tags: categorical-encoding, james-stein-estimator

> **Better encoding of categorical data can mean better model performance.**

> The [James–Stein estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James%E2%80%93Stein_estimator) is a biased estimator of the mean of Gaussian random vectors. It can be shown that the James–Stein estimator dominates the "ordinary" least squares approach, i.e., it has a lower mean squared error. It is the best-known example of Stein's phenomenon.

Can someone explain how James-Stein Estimator is used for Categorical Encoding and how it works? And how the lower mean squared error is achieved?

Comment: What connection do you see between the JSE and how data are encoded?  Neither seems to have anything to do with the other, either conceptually, mathematically, or practically.